# Clipping a NetCDF file with a regionmask in python

Tags: python, mask, netcdf, geo, clip

I have monthly estimates of PM 2.5 for 20 consecutive years stored in NetCDF files with a precision of 0.01°x0.01° (i.e. for each 0.01°x0.01° square on the world map, there is an estimate of PM 2.5). [The data is here for those interested.](https://sites.wustl.edu/acag/datasets/surface-pm2-5/)

I wish to clip the NetCDF files with a geodataframe containing the bounding boxes of the cities I am interested in and then make an average of the PM 2.5 for each city (as they might be in more than one 0.01°x0.01° square). The geodataframe has the following form :

```
cities    longmin    latmin    longmax    latmax    WKT

Rennes    -1.72      48.08     -1.61      48.15    POLYGON ((-1.72 48.08, -1.61 48.08, -1.61 48.15, -1.72 48.15, -1.72 48.08))

Bursa     29.01      40.17      29.15     40.23    POLYGON ((29.01 40.17, 29.15 40.17, 29.15 40.23, 29.01 40.23, 29.01 40.17))

Copenhagen12.45      55.61      12.67     55.73    POLYGON ((12.45 55.61, 12.67 55.61, 12.67 55.73, 12.45 55.73, 12.45 55.61))

...
```

I was advised to use regionmask by Michael Delgado in another post, and following [this model](https://www.guillaumedueymes.com/post/shapefiles_country/) I think I have created a mask with the cities, I applied it (atleast I think so) and I now try to export the clipped NetCDF file to a .csv file. The code is the following

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import regionmask
       
## Importing the NetCDF file with xarray

ds_temp2 = xr.open_dataset('/path/to/file/V5GL01.HybridPM25.Global.201912-201912.nc')
ds_temp2


## Creating a geodataframe with the bounded boxes of the cities file

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/lucius/Documents/MiR/Data1/bounding_boxes.xls')
print(df)
df['geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['geometry'])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')


## Creating the mask for the NetCDF file

my_list = list(gdf['cities'])
my_list_unique = set(list(gdf['cities']))
indexes = [my_list.index(x) for x in my_list_unique]
gdf_mask_poly = regionmask.Regions(name = 'cities', numbers = indexes, names = gdf.cities[indexes], abbrevs = gdf.cities[indexes], outlines = list(gdf.geometry.values[i] for i in range(0,gdf.shape[0])))    
gdf_mask_poly

## Applying the mask to the NetCDF file
mask = gdf_mask_poly.mask(ds_temp2, lat_name='lat', lon_name='lon')

## Filtering the data where the mask is not located
cropped_ds_temp2 = ds_temp2.where(mask, drop=True)
```

After approximately an hour, the console stopped running and the mask was created.

How may I verify that the NetCDF file (that is now an xarray object) has been successfully clipped? It still has the same dimensions : 'lon': 34000, 'lat' :12300.

I am a beginner in python, please forgive me if this question may seem simple to you.

Comment: I'm confused. What is your question? You start of claiming that you have failed to clip the netcdf. Then you end by asking how to convert a successfully clipped netcdf to csv.

Comment: Forgive me, I mixed up a former draft and my actual question. I'd like to verify that the file was successfully clipped; how could I proceed?

Comment: You just need to plot the data